# Rails: How do I call `self.save` in my model and have it persist in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, persistence

I'm trying to keep model logic within my model, but I can't get it to perform modifications on itself and have them persist in the database.

In my controller:

```
@article.perform_some_calulcations!
```

In my model:

```
def perform_some_calculations!
  self.foo.gsub!(/regexp/, 'string')
  self.save
end
```

If I drop `debugger` statements into my method and after my call to it in the controller, `@article.foo` has the correct value. However, when I continue, it doesn't persist in the database and webrick doesn't report any `UPDATE` statements.

What's going wrong? I don't know if I've ever had to do this before, but surely it's possible right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your problem was that if you modify an attribute "in place", this means: without assigning it a new value, then Rails will think that there is nothing new to be saved, so it "optimizes" the save away.

Each write accessor of your attribute will set a flag, so the save method will know that it should check whether the current value really differs from the value read from the database.
That's why `self.foo = self.foo.gsub(/regexp/, 'string')` works *(note that the exclamation mark is not necessary here)*.

If you need to modify an attribute "in place", for example with `gsub!` or `replace`, use:

```
def perform_some_calculations!
  foo_will_change!
  self.foo.gsub!(/regexp/, 'string')
  self.save
end
```

Comment: Is this a good practice? i.e. the model calling save on itself after calculating something?

Comment: It may be subjective, but I do not see anything wrong per se in an object saving itself when it's necessary. _Overusing_ this pattern  may be bad for the performance, though.

Answer (score 2):

Your attributes might be protected. Check your log. IF that is the case then

```
self.save!
```

or

```
self.save(false)
```

---

try taking the exclamation point off your definition.

---

```
self.foo = self.foo.gsub!(/regexp/, 'string')
```

Comment: Good idea, but `self.save!` and `self.save(false)` both have the same result. No sign of `attr_protected` anywhere or any warnings in the webrick log.

Comment: No dice with removing the `!` from the method name

Comment: heh, I just discovered that independently :P Why does it need explicit assignment if you use `gsub!`?

Comment: I see what you mean because you are doing it in place, but apparently it doesn't work like that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create a method in a class to modify itself base on an argument. Using `.save` or `.save!` did not work for me, but if I used

```
self.update!({<PROP_NAME>: <NEW_VALUE>})
```

I saw the changes persisted in my database.